# Excessive mistake in android GPS locations

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I have an application that saves the tablet GPS location in a database every 2 minute.

I get my location points from `LocationManager`.

I have locations in my database that the programmatic accuracy is about 50 and real accuracy sometimes is about 200 meters.

Yesterday I saw for the first time that 5 successive locations in my database are about 1000KM far from other points.

What can be the reason of these mistakes? How can I avoid them?

**Update:**

If there is no solution to improve GPS points, is there any algorithm for refining outlying locations?

Comment: GPS is far from 100% accurate and depends on how many satellites you can see.  But there is no way anyone can answer this, as written, without guessing.  If you think you have a problem with your code, then you should post your code.  But if you think this is a problem with the GPS locations, then trying to understand the issue may be better for [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Very good question, I have code which seems to be doing the same at the moment. I even get the accuracy and only use results with an accuracy of less than 50 meters and I still get complaints saying that they are showing up about 1 mile out!

Answer (score 0):

Although 1000km seems an enormous precision rate, check if your app is really using GPS, rather than network location. With cell-based location (no GPS) it's not hard to get some kms in precision.

You can get more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)